# Integrity constraint violation: How to join two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am making a program for a school project in laravel, so I try to join two tables: products and destinations

The table Product has the columns: id, name

The Destinations table has this columns: Destinations:id,product_id,destination,quantity,target_person

and I need to join `product_id` and `id`

```
products = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('destinations','id','=','destinations.product_id ')
    ->get();
```

but when I try to use `LEFT JOIN` I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `products` inner join `destinations` on `id` = `destinations`.`product_id`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use Table reference `products.id`

```
products = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('destinations','products.id','=','destinations.product_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Worked,but i get the following error :SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'destinations.product_id ' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `products` left join `destinations` on `products`.`id` = `destinations`.`product_id `)
but i have this column in my db

Comment: i have update my answer and i remove space at the end of `product_id`

Comment: don't forget to accept correct answer. accepted answer will help in future to other user

Answer (score 2):

Is because it does not know if 'id' is refering to the one in products or destinations.
Try this:

```
products = DB::table('products')
->leftJoin('destinations','products.id','=','destinations.product_id')

->get();
```